# How would Earth map look like if all ice melts?

Tags: climate-change, sea-level, glaciology, ice, glaciation

Is there somewhere a map which indicates which areas and cities become sea?

Comment: Yes: https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2013/09/rising-seas-ice-melt-new-shoreline-maps/

Answer (score 7):

[Calculated Earth](https://calculatedearth.com/index.php) is one of the better tools for this, you can either zoom in and get various flood stages or set a specific flood stage and see what would flood, it is in metric though so you may need some [conversion software](https://www.metric-conversions.org/length/feet-to-meters.htm) to deal with the units for you, depending how familiar you are with metric.

Answer (score 2):

The latest estimations of global land ice mass suggest they have enough water to [rise sea level in 66.5 m](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444635242000051).

With this value you can go on and produce a global map (or one of you area of interest) at [Calculated Earth](https://calculatedearth.com/index.php) as @Ash suggested. I agree is a good tool.

I've created an animated GIF using two maps produced at [Calculated Earth](https://calculatedearth.com/index.php) with current sea level and +66.5m, so you can easily see the changes:
[image]

The [National Geographic maps](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2013/09/rising-seas-ice-melt-new-shoreline-maps/) (suggested by @Gimelist) are very nice too, and are based in a slightly different figure of 65.8 m (216 ft).

Note that this is just a thought experiment, because the melting of all land ice would have to be encompassed by a significant increase in temperature. Such increase in temperature would also produce a very important sea level rise due to thermal expansion. The magnitude of that rise depends on the temperature rise and the time scale, as the oceans take in the order of millennia to equilibrarte with changes in atmospheric conditions.

Comment: Also there is [Post-glacial rebound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-glacial_rebound).

Comment: Yes, isostatic rebound that would also work at long time scales, and many other effects, like sediment transport that will things even more complicated when modelling realistic sea level rise.

Comment: For a more subtle effect, I suspect that the geoid would alter (and hence the relation of sea level in one place to sea level in another place) thanks to the redistrubution of all that mass from the poles. No idea of the scale of this effect, from millimetres to metres... actually, I might need to ask a question on this when I get time :)

Comment: I assume, in that plot, that one should pay no attention to the enlargement of inland seas/lakes? Presumably that's at least partially independent of sea level, so long as the basins remain landlocked.

Comment: I always use 70m; some thermal expansion of the upper layers of the ocean should be added.